# Is pipe terminated when i have destroyed its writing end?

Tags: c

I have parent process that creates two child processes. First child will write to pipe and second child will read from the pipe. After 5 seconds parent will terminate first child.(so its write end should be automatically closed, isn't it?). I need second child to terminate automatically, because it uses pipe and after first child is terminated, the pipe should be terminated too. My problem: how can i force child 2 to die immediately when child 1 i killed?(i don't need child 2 to print something after child 1 is dead, even if he still has any information in the pipe buffer to read). Should i use pipe2 instead of simple pipe?

```
void do_close(int fd){
    if(close(fd) != 0){
        perror("close");
        exit(2);
    }

}
void signalhandler(int signum){
    fprintf(stderr, "f1 terminated!\n");
    exit(1);
}
int main(){
pid_t f1 = -1, f2 = -1;
int pipefd[2];
if(pipe(pipefd) == -1){
    perror("pipe");
    exit(2);
}
f1 = fork();
if(f1 > 0){
    f2 = fork();
}

if(f1 > 0 && f2 > 0){
    do_close(pipefd[0]);
    do_close(pipefd[1]);
    sleep(5);
    kill(f1, SIGTERM);  
    waitpid(f1, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(f2, NULL, 0);
}
else if(f1 == 0){
    signal(SIGTERM, signalhandler);
    do_close(pipefd[0]);
    while(1){
        fflush(stdout);
        write(pipefd[1], "Hello world!\n", 13);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
else if(f2 == 0){
    do_close(pipefd[1]);
    char *buf = (char*)malloc(13);
        while(read(pipefd[0], buf, 13) > 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
                printf("%c", buf[i]);
            }
            sleep(3);
        }

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You can only detect that the writing end was closed by reading all bytes still buffered in the pipe and then reading `0` bytes, denoting EOF. When you observe that, terminate the second child explicitly by calling exit()

Comment: Your second child *is* terminating "automatically" (i.e., by detecting a zero read), it's just that due to the `sleep(3)` line, it will keep reading from the pipe buffer for a little while after `f1` died, until it reaches the end of the pipe buffer.

(BTW, you can write the buffer out at once with `fwrite`, and you should be accounting for the possibility of partial `reads`/`writes` as well)

Answer (score 2):

"Terminated" isn't the usual terminology for a pipe, and it might be causing a slight misunderstanding. The termination of the writing process isn't immediately "felt" by the reader if there is still data in the buffer.

To summarize the program, you have one process that writes to a pipe at a rate of 1 line per second for 5 seconds, then dies. Another process reads from the pipe at a rate of 1 line every 3 seconds until EOF or error, then exits.

The lines are small and fixed-size so there's no chance of reading an incomplete line.

Nothing in the program should cause an error on the pipe, so the second child process will read until EOF.

EOF on a pipe occurs when 2 conditions are met: there are no writers, and the buffer is empty. The death of the first child process accomplishes the first condition. The second condition is not immediately true, because at the 5 second mark, there have been 5 lines written to the pipe, and only 2 of them have been read (one at the start, and one after 3 seconds).

The second child process keeps reading, pulling in the remaining lines, and eventually exits after about 5*3=15 seconds.

(The timing isn't infinitely precise, so you aren't guaranteed to get exactly 5 lines written to the pipe. When I ran it I got 6.)